# mysql insert into table using prepare statement

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

[image: workbench]

I want to insert the record into table by using values returned by execution of prepare statement 
please provide alternative

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not just use `insert select`:

```
insert into testtable
select * from testtable where id = 1;
```

Or if you have to use prepare statement, you should use it like this:

```
set @str = 'insert into testtable
            select * from testtable where id = 1;'

PREPARE st FROM @str;
EXECUTE st;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE st;
```

Comment: cause my prepare statement is dynamic

Comment: @karanyadav if the answer is correct you should mark it as correct